# Fancybox loading on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm using fancybox 1.3.4 for some images on a website, using the following code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
    });
```

For some reason fancybox is loading by bother hover and click - I don't want it to trigger on hover, does anyone know why this is happening? I couldn't find anything in the docs to suggest how to fix this.

Comment: `$(image).click(function(){ $(this).fancybox(); })`

Comment: Thanks for the help. For this I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined

Comment: Sorry my bad edited comment... Try new one

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the fancybox to not trigger at all.

Comment: Try this one `$(image).click(function(){ $("a.fancybox").fancybox(); })`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: image is not defined

Comment: In the code you posted nothing is wrong. Display on click (and not on hover) is expected behavior. I guess something is broken elsewhere... Is the page public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox().trigger('click');
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes the fancybox to not trigger.